# Error de validación en formulario de Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formularios, mongodb

Me gustaría saber a que se debe el error de autenticación que aparece al rellenar un formulario para un registro de usuarios. Al introducir todos los campos y parámetros adecuadamente, me dice que hay un error de contraseñas (aún así de haberlas introducido).
Estoy utilizando como base de datos MongoDB.

**El error**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El Debug**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

   private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `user_params` está definido dos veces, y en la segunda definición (la cual es la que realmente se utiliza) únicamente permites `:name` y `:email`:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
end
```

Lo que tienes que hacer es dejar una definición en la que permitas también los campos de contraseña, es decir, eliminar la segunda definición del método y dejar la primera.

Pero ojo, tienes esa primer definición bajo `private` a la mitad de tu controlador, y debería estar al final (de lo contrario las acciones `update` y `destroy` no estarán disponibles).

Así se debería ver tu controlador:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Comment: efectivamente, fallo mío!! muchas gracias!!!

Comment: @martagrrz Que bueno que funcionó! Por favor no olvides aceptar la respuesta (dando clic en la paloma). Suerte!

Comment: Llevo poco en esta plataforma.. Gracias!!!!